# Error with renamed repo in GitHub: "remote: This repository moved. Please use the new location"

Tags: git

I am receiving this notice when I push updates from my local instance to remote master on GitHub:

> `remote: This repository moved. Please use the new location [new location]`

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 482, accepted):

The simple way is:

```
git remote set-url origin [updated link url https://........git]
```

Alternatively, if you like the long way it is:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin [updated link]
```

[Changing a remote's URL](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/) GitHub documentation goes into further detail.

Comment: Presumably you need to use the `git@github.com:...git` or similar URL if connecting using ssh? My error message listed the new `https` scheme URL, but it was the `git@` URL that I actually needed to set as the origin. `git remote show origin` will tell you what URL scheme you are using currently.

Comment: `git remote -v` will also show what urls you have set.

Comment: Would be better if you could swap your solutions to first one = best one. I started typing your old solution before I saw the shorter one.

Comment: I have just done that @Dodekeract because that was my reaction too!

Comment: @ErichBSchulz thanks for the edit, hopefully that saves people time. Cheers.

Comment: set-url will not work when using SSH. The long way worked fine.

Comment: Do not forget to add the upstream for the new repo URL. at the first push you will get an error. just use `git push --set-upstream origin master`.

Comment: I have this error but the remote URL is exactly what it should be. I even tried deleting the repo and doing a fresh clone and I still get the same problem any ideas?

Comment: @Brad I can help you troubleshoot, how is best to contact you?

Comment: @jamescampbell git hub was down at the time. Was affecting everyone and GitHub actions as well. All came good a few hours later.

Answer (score 82):

To check the current one:

```
git remote -v
```

Then to change it:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPO.git
```

Comment: I did this, and the remote origin is correct but i still get this message

Answer (score 14):

This is an upgrade on the answers I found.
Check the current one :

```
git remote -v
```

With the above command you will get a result like

```
origin  https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPO (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPO (push)
```

Note this, here is the difference, it **MAY NOT** always be origin.

You write the command based on what you found. So if it was origin,
Then you change it like :

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPO
```

If it was upstream, you change it like:

```
git remote set-url upstream https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPO
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was breaking up my huge commit into smaller commits, starting with the file deletions.